# UWP Xaml disabled GridViewItem background control leaking into view

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have following Xaml

```
<GridView x:Name="DeviceTargets"
            ContainerContentChanging="GridViewContainerContentChanging"
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Margin="0 14 0 10"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="OnDeviceTargetsItemClicked"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyleSV}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeviceList, Mode=OneWay}"
            Padding="0"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:DeviceViewModel">
            <local:DeviceItem ViewModel="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

DeviceItem control:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemRootGridStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <local:BadgedPersonPicture
        x:Name="DeviceBadge"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Contact="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeviceContact, Mode=OneWay}" 
        BadgeImageSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeviceBadgeImage, Mode=OneWay}" />

    <local:TwoLinesTextBlock
        x:Name="DeviceName"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeviceDisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

BadgedPersonPicture control :

```
<Grid Width="64">
    <PersonPicture
        Width="48"
        Height="48"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Contact="{x:Bind Contact, Mode=OneWay}"
        ProfilePicture="{x:Bind ProfilePicture, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Ellipse Width="23" Height="23" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{ThemeResource PersonBadgeBackgroundBrush}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    <Ellipse Width="23" Height="23" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{ThemeResource PersonBadgeBorderBrush}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind BadgeImageSource, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="None"></ImageBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

When I disable some of the GridViewItem, it shows as following

[image]

As you can in red box, border from the control in the background is leaking into view. Any idea how I can make it look like the one that is not disabled as far as controls in the front and back are concerned?

Note: text under the image is intentionally obfuscated.

Update:
Attaching the badge image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code with my own image. But the BadgeImage image is not transparented like the image you shared. Would you please share the image you are using for profile and badge ?

Comment: Thanks Roy Li for trying this on your end. I attached the badge image to the original post. And for profile, it is not an image, it is based on initials.

Comment: Do you mean `ProfilePicture` is null? There is no value for it and it uses a system generated image?

Comment: I reproduced this behavior on my side. I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this and talked with the team about this. A possible reason is that when you disable the item, it gets a transparent filter on it which will change how it looks like. This behavior is by design.

After discussion, if you want to avoid this behavior, the possible solution is to manually create style which looks like the item is disabled. Apply the style to the item instead of disabling the item.

Comment: I tried the same approach. I created a new style and set opacity to 0.55 in it. I got the same result. So the opacity is creating this behavior.

Comment: @rsp Please do not change the opacity and try other style like set the item grey or something else which will indicate the item is not available